# Upload to Ionic Cloud with specific credentials

Tags: ionic2, ionic-cli, ionic-cloud

I have 2 different accounts in Ionic Cloud, one is personal and the other is the professional one.

I've logged out from both of them and then I want to create a new app_id in my professional account.

So I run `$ionic io init` to generate the account, but the app gets created in my personal account no matter what I do.

Is there any way to specify the credentials when generating the app? Or does anybody know how to definitely log out of the account for ionic-cli?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered in the [github account](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cloud-issues/issues/268), so I'm posting the answer just in case finds it useful.

Just with `$ionic login` I can change the current account.